# Finding order of $f(z) = \cos\sqrt z$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

What is the order of following entire function: $$f(z) = \cos\sqrt z$$

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! I'm sorry but can you explain what you mean with order of the integral function?

Comment: what is meant by an integral function and what do you mean by order of it?

Comment: integral function: Analytic in the entire complex plane ("ganze Funktion").

Comment: The order of an entire function is defined as: $$\inf\left\{\alpha\in\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}:\forall\varepsilon>0, |f(z)|\ll\exp(|z|^{\alpha+\varepsilon})\text{ as }|z|\to +\infty.\right\}.$$

Comment: The correct term is "entire function". "Entire" and "integral" translate to the same word in many languages.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(z)=\cos\sqrt{z} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\exp(i z^{1/2})+\exp(-i z^{1/2})\right). $$
Hence the order of $f(z)$ is just $\dfrac{1}{2}$: the upper bound follows from the previous line, the lower bound from the position of the roots of $f(z)$ - it is useful to recall that if $\beta$ is the exponent of convergence of the zeroes of $f(z)$, then $\beta\leq\alpha$.